# Performing Actions without opening browser using Selenium

Tags: java

I know that we can use Selenium to open a browser through a drive. However I was wondering if it was possible to have a program that does stuff on a website in the *background* and have a log tell the user what is going on?

E.g: run program ~> the console tells user that is on Google... ~> is searching for whatever input ~> found x hits or so.

Comment: Selenium already produces logs, so you could just get it to open Firefox in a framebuffer program, so that you don't see it. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19127641/472495).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/).

It is a headless browser, which means, it doesn't have a GUI to show, and does its work in the background.

Comment: Does this let you make your own console that then does everything with the headless browser

Comment: @NoobProgrammer if you're talking about running from the console, yes. It does not show up any window. Precisely, it does not have any window.